# trying to install 3 HDD

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, cd-drive

so I am trying to install 2 extra HDD drives into a windows XP computer and they install fine and work but when I add the 3rd HDD the CD drive will not show up in the My computer window. 
so the question is, is there a way to fix this issue or is best to leave the 3rd HDD out of the system.

Comment: Could you add more info - what kind of interface do HDD have? Did you check if BIOS recognized all 3 HDD?

Comment: it regonized all of the HDDs they are IEEE hard drives

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "My Computer", select *manage*, and under *storage* click *Disk Management*.
Do all your drives and the CD show up in this window? Does each have a drive letter associated with it?

Comment: did that as well the HDD's show up but the CD drive does not

Comment: If these are SATA drives, have you gone into the BIOS to make sure all 4 channels are actually active? I know, on some of our Dells, the SATA channels are not auto detect- you have to click to turn them on.

Comment: they are all PATA drives

Comment: If they are all PATA drives, have you made sure of the jumper position on all of them? Easiest thing is to make sure all are set for cable-select. Next check that both cables are good. You might try other cables.

Comment: yes I have checked the jumpers. I have one HDD set for master and all the rest are set as slave, I did not use cable select due to the lack of space. all the cables work.

Comment: Each channel can only have 1 master and 1 slave. if you have 4 drives, you have 2 on each of 2 cables. Then you should have a master and a slave set on each cable. Or, set all to cable select and be done with it.

Comment: so let me get this straight each cable has to have a master and a slave for each IEEE cable.

Comment: that's it. welcome to 1985